# How to use a Result[String] in Scala match expression

Tags: scala, match

In the following code the first expression returns a Result[String] which contains one of the strings "medical", "dental" or "pharmacy" inside of a Result. I can add .toOption.get to the end of the val statement to get the String, but is there a better way to use the Result? Without the .toOption.get, the code will not compile.

```
val service = element("h2").containingAnywhere("claim details").fullText()
    service match {
      case "medical" => extractMedicalClaim
      case "dental" => extractDentalClaim
      case "pharmacy" => extractPharmacyClaim
    }
```

Comment: Where is the `Result` class defined? Part of some framework? It's not a standard scala class as far as I can tell, and hard to answer without documentation for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing what `Result` is. If it's a `case class`, with the target `String` as part of its constructor, then you could pattern match directly.

Something like this.

```
service match {
  case Result("medical")  => extractMedicalClaim
  case Result("dental")   => extractDentalClaim
  case Result("pharmacy") => extractPharmacyClaim
  case _ => // default result
}
```

If the `Result` class doesn't have an extractor (the `upapply()` method) you might be able to add one just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this `Result[T]` class has a `toOption` method which returns an `Option[T]` - if that's the case, you can call `toOption` and match on that option:

```
val service = element("h2").containingAnywhere("claim details").fullText().toOption
service match {
  case Some("medical") => extractMedicalClaim
  case Some("dental") => extractDentalClaim
  case Some("pharmacy") => extractPharmacyClaim
  case None => // handle the case where the result was empty
}
```

Comment: or just to act on non-empty, `x.toOption.foreach { case "med" => ??? }`.